# save correct value type

Tags: macos, swift3, xcode8

i have a textfield where the user should enter a price like 20,00
this value i would like to save into core data. i chose the attribute type double - i hope this is correct.

if i request the data and show it as print result, i get this output:
20.0

but i need 20.00
and later i can change the "." to ",".
how can I get the second missing null?

Comment: A printed representation of a number is not the number itself. Save the value. Then when you want to *display* it, you choose the proper formatting. The same value is displayable in several different ways.

Comment: proper formatting? have you a little example for me?

Comment: okay i got it: `String(format: "%.02f EUR", locale: Locale.current, arguments: [20,00])` thanks a lot

Comment: Nice! Good find. You're welcome.